# Fuchsia OS Failed to start the emulator

Tags: operating-system, fuchsia

I am trying to install fuchsia and it was downloaded perfectly , but when I tried to start the emulator , it popped waiting for emulator to start and then it failed, giving error
device, health check failed . Unable to ssh due to error : exit status 2

Then, when I checked the log file for error:
It showed This application failed to start because no QT platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling application may fix the problem.

#I have tried to reinstall 2-3 times, tried every possible thing, qt was installed properly even qtcreator was working, still while running fuchsia same error is coming

Any answers?Any solution

Comment: Thanks for your question. Some additional details about the commands you used to build and run FEMU, as well as the exact error output, would be helpful in determining a cause.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.